# CO2 is attracted to what?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry

People are using filters to remove $\ce{CO2}$ from the air.

What are this filters made of and are there any other substances that attract $\ce{CO2}$?

How is $\ce{CO2}$ absorbed or attracted to these substances?

P.S: Sorry, I did not get any suitable Tags for this.

Comment: The following wikipedia article does summarize different used techniques: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carbon_dioxide_scrubber